# Actuator Endpoint has health endpoint listed but independent call to health endpoint fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring boot application that has the following dependency added.

```
      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

On hitting the /actuator/ endpoint , I get the below response.

> {​​​​​​​​"_links":{​​​​​​​​"self":{​​​​​​​​"href":"http://IP:PORT/actuator","templated":false}​​​​​​​​,"health":{​​​​​​​​"href":"http://IP:PORT/actuator/health","templated":false}​​​​​​​​,"info":{​​​​​​​​"href":"http://IP:PORT/actuator/info","templated":false}​​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​​

Similarly on hitting the /info/ endpoint , I get an empty {} response.

But the endpoint /health/ does not return any response and keeps on loading.
As per my understanding the `/actuator/` , `/actuator/info/` , `/actuator/health/` are enabled by default when an actuator dependency is added.
So, why is this not working in my case?

Comment: Adding this in application properties? `management.endpoint.health.show-details=always`

Comment: If you get no response, it sounds like one of the health indicators is misbehaving. Can you take a thread dump once you've made a request to `/actuator/health` that doesn't get a response and add it to your question? If you're not familiar with taking a thread dump, one way to do so is with `jstack` on the command line.